# Image sorting problem

Tags: jquery

I am trying to sort some images using jQuery. I refered to http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid and it's working. But the problem is that when I try to sort the images by dragging them from left to right, my form gets moved to left (but when I do the opposite it works perfectly). I have tried setting up margins and all but it's not working. How can I get the behavior I want?

Comment: Please post an example that demonstrates the problem. http://jsfiddle.net is a great webapp for this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes Matt. I have a form which has an image gallery and some containers. I allow users to drag and drop the images from the gallery. After dropping I have to allow the users to sort the images within the containers(by dragging only) . But while dragging the images within the container, the form gets shifted to the left(while dragging from left to right whereas it works perfectly when I drag from right and drop at some position to the left of it). After dropping it looks the way it should be. Its the distortion that I want to remove.

Comment: Post some example code so we can get an idea of what you're trying to accomplish. Hard to help you without seeing code.

Comment: The problem is solved. I just changed the size of the image in the container and it does not produce the distortion any more. Thanks for the comments guys.

Comment: @user556773: You should post that as a self-answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I just changed the size of the image in the container and it does not produce the distortion any more. Thanks for the comments guys.